# Standard way to implement login or signup in Spring

Tags: spring

I have to implement a login authentication & user registration feature for my product.

What is the standard and effective way of doing this using spring which would provide standard security (meaning nothing super fancy, but nothing easy to get around as well)?

As this has been done so many times there has to be a standard way to achieve this ?

The implementation should include :

1. user registration form after registering through g+ or fb etc
2. login form
3. storing user profiles, passwords, preferences in some backend
   db or system
4. role management : different roles like admin would have
   access to all etc

Standard : that which can put in production.

I found too many things scattered all around the net and although this seems like a broad topic its difficult to get started with especially when this going straight into production and not as a hobby project. The tutorials are always good to get started however are a starting point only. I want to know whats the best route or path that can be used for a product in production.

Answer (score 1):

Securing a web application is not small topic, so you will need to read some tutorials. 
You'll find very quick an easy to understand guides (with working examples)
at Spring Boot guides web site.

[Spring Boot guides](https://spring.io/guides)

[Securing web application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

[JPA for your hibernate requirement](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

If you want going deeper you could read these great tutorials:

[Spring security form login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Comment: yes but I found too many things scattered all around the net. The tutorials are always good to get started however are a starting point only. I want to know whats the best route or path that can be used for a product in production.

Comment: All the tutorials from baeldung you can use in production. I have built many application using all those tutorials as reference.